# How to create new tabs/sheets from each additions to a column?

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a CRM for my small business.
Would like that each time I add a company name it creates a new tab/sheet in the same spreadsheet for that company follow-ups and notes.
Is this possible how?

Sheet to occur on: CRM Column to take names for tabs from: E1:E (Company)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work Correctly

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;  //gets cell to edit
  var companyName = range.getValue();  //gets value of cell
  var column = range.getColumn();  //gets the column number of the cell
  var thisSheetNumber = range.getSheet().getIndex();

  //make sure this is the correct column on the correct sheet
  if (column == 5 && thisSheetNumber == 1)                       
  {
    //searches for a sheet that matches the companyName
    var sheetNotFound = true;    
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();

    for (var i = 0; i<sheets.length; i++)                     
    {
      //if it finds matching sheet stops
      if (sheets[i].getName() == companyName)                                 
      {
        sheetNotFound = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    //else creates the sheet
    if (sheetNotFound)  
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet(companyName);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will do it. The trigger is contained in the function name.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;  //gets cell to edit
  var companyName = range.getValue();  //gets value of cell
  var column = range.getColumn();  //gets the column number of the cell
  var thisSheetNumber = range.getSheet().getIndex();

  //make sure this is the correct column on the correct sheet
  if (column == 5 && thisSheetNumber == 1){
     //searches for a sheet that matches the companyName
     var sheetNotFound = true;    
     var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();

     for (var i = 0; i<sheets.length; i++){
        //if it finds matching sheet stops
        if (sheets[i].getName() == companyName){
           sheetNotFound = false;
           break;
          }
       }
//else creates the sheet
if (sheetNotFound){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet(companyName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that using a reserved word (onEdit) for a function that will be called by a trigger is not a good practice b/c this leads to confusions and could make it harder to debug / maintain. By the other hand, please add a explanation of what your code does and how it works.

Comment: Added comments. Yeah, the trigger and the name were redundant as using the reserved name meant I didn't need set up a separate trigger that did the same thing.

Comment: Bear in mind that functions called by simple triggers can't do all the things than functions called by installable triggers. Did you tested your script by calling it by a simple trigger instead of using an installable trigger?

Comment: It worked as the scope is limited to the document.